# UILabel frame equals CGRectZero inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel, frame, cgrect

I'm using a UICollectionView in my application and I a few labels inside the UICollectionViewCell and I access these labels like so:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID forIndexPath: indexPath];
...
UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag: 2];
```

My label has dynamic height for each individual UICollectionViewCell, so I'm trying to retrieve the `nameLabel.frame` but it always gives out `(x: 0, y: 0, h: 0, w: 0)`.
I tried changing every possible property of the label, but still nothing.
BTW I can set the text and play with the label no problem (the IBOutlet is set correctly).

**The UICollectionView, the cell and the label are all loaded from a storyboard file**

Any of you experienced this bug with UILabels storyboards?

***EDIT:***
Thanks to `verbumdei`'s comment I disabled the autoLayout and it seems to solve these issues with the frames. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you try to log the frame? Do you use auto-layout?

Comment: The autolayout is checked. And I log it right after I retrieve a pointer to it. I managed to work it out by subclassing the cell - it fixed the problem

Comment: Glad the issue is solved :)